# Linux get current time from Host-PC

Tags: c, linux, shell, batch-file, time

I am looking for a solution for a time synchronization problem. I want my linux microcontroller to sync with the current time on my windows PC, whenever I connect both. 
There might be a solution with a NTP-Server, but I do not want to change values in the registry neither want to install extra programms on my pc. Is there a way to send the time information from windows to my linux system? I was thinking about some linux commands like "ping", but just one with the time as a return value.

Thanks!

FT

Comment: Well, trivial protocols will not work well because of large and/or variable latencies.

Comment: I don't need the time that precisely, so regular latencies about some seconds are okay. Currently I dont know how to send from linux commands to windows and get the date/time as a return value.

Comment: SNTP might help.